# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Throwing this error on this line Edit_English.Text = aEdit_English; in the following code...

```
 protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button EditButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("EditButton");
    Button SaveButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("SaveButton");
        TitleLanguage.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
        LanguageView.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
        EditButton.Visible = false; 
        SaveButton.Visible = true;
        TextBox Edit_English = (TextBox)ContentLoginView.FindControl("Edit_English");
        TextBox Edit_French = (TextBox)ContentLoginView.FindControl("Edit_French");
        TextBox Edit_FrenchT = (TextBox)TitleLoginView.FindControl("Edit_FrenchT");
        TextBox Edit_EnglishT = (TextBox)TitleLoginView.FindControl("Edit_EnglishT");
        Edit_English.Text = aEdit_English;
        Edit_French.Text = aEdit_French;
        Edit_EnglishT.Text = aEdit_EnglishT;
        Edit_FrenchT.Text = aEdit_FrenchT;




}
```

Here is the page markup along with it. When I type in visual studio it has no problem accessing contentloginview.

```
<asp:MultiView ID="LanguageView" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="English" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="en_content" runat="server"/></asp:View>
             <asp:View ID="French" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="fr_content" runat="server"/></asp:View>
   <asp:View ID="Edit" runat="server">
       <asp:LoginView ID="ContentLoginView" runat="server">
           <LoggedInTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_English" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
               <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_French" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
           </LoggedInTemplate>
       </asp:LoginView>  
   </asp:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox Edit_English = (TextBox)ContentLoginView.FindControl("Edit_English");
```

That line is returning you null and you are assuming it was properly found.

`FindControl` only searches for controls that are directly under the control `FindControl` was called on. In this case `ContentLoginView`. `LoggedInTemplate` is probably what's throwing a wrench in things.

[It could also be an issue with Master Pages.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-vb)

Comment: this was correct... still had trouble accessing it through a login view... maybe because it is also in a multiview? either way I found another work around for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because there is no aEdit_English string variable (or other object that can be converted with .ToString()).  aEdit_English is null.

I would suggest trying to locate where this variable is being declared and making sure that it is contained within the proper scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** there is no control with ID `Edit_EnglishT` in your design page.

so `Edit_EnglisT` in below statement becomes `null`.

```
TextBox Edit_EnglishT = (TextBox)TitleLoginView.FindControl("Edit_EnglishT");
```

when you try to call any members(ex: `Text` property) thhrows above mentioned Excetion.

**Solution :** before trying to assign value to the `Edit_EnglishT` control you just verify wether it is really found or not.

Try This:

```
if(Edit_EnglishT != null)
    Edit_EnglishT.Text = aEdit_EnglishT;
```